# Container of pointers to containers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

How am i supposed to create new elements in container of pointers to containers?

I have code of filling adjacency lists, so i need a list of adjacent nodes for every vertex(aka index in vector, input is edjes, sorted by first node)

```
typedef list<int>  adjListType;
typedef vector<adjListType*> graphType;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
graphType graph;
ifstream ifs("SCC1.txt");

int key, value, prev_key = 0;
list<int> adjList;
while (ifs >> key >> value)
{
    if (prev_key != 0 && prev_key != key)
    {
        graph.push_back(&adjListType(adjList));
        adjList = list<int>();
    }
    adjList.push_back(value);
    prev_key = key;
}

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

adjList is filling fine, but turns out that elements in graph are just empty lists

Comment: Does it have to be pointers? Can you not just have a `std::vector<std::list<int>>`?

Comment: You push back a pointer to an element in list `adjList` and then you clear this list. Where should the pointers point to now? Why have a list if you are going to clear it every time?

Comment: @Galik it's easier, yes. But i just want to know how am i supposed to do this

Comment: I didn't notice adjListType is a typedef here so my comment may be wrong.

Comment: Well you are probably "supposed" to do it without pointers, as that's easier. If you really want to do it the hardway.. it's not clear what data you want to end up with and in what layout.

Comment: @NeilKirk I push back a pointer to a copy, and after that I erase original vector.

Comment: Make sure you use a modern compiler with high warning level, as your code is actually non-standard. http://ideone.com/i9dXot

Comment: The copy you point to, has to still exist when you use the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
graph.push_back(&adjListType(adjList));
```

Remove the &. What happens here is that you create a new adjListType with content of adjList, get a pointer to that stack object and add it to graph. The scope of that object is however limited to your if so it gets destroyed soon after.

You don't really have to use pointers of list here, it will reduce performance a tiny bit but will save you headaches

Comment: Removing just the `&` will no longer compile so I don't see how that is a solution.